# Get MiKTeX dvips to embed fonts found in EPS file

Tags: fonts, miktex, eps, embedding

I have some EPS figures embedded in a LaTeX document. When I run dvips on the .dvi file I get complaints like this:

```
dvips.exe: Font TimesTen-Roman used in file ./fig01-01.eps is not in the mapping file.
```

Note that I *do* have the Adobe Type 1 font for TimesTen-Roman, but I do not know how to get dvips to associate the font it finds in the EPS file with that file and to put it into the generated Postscript.

I am using MiKTeX 2.9.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried compiling the tex file with something like `dvipdfm` command? I usually do that when i have .eps figres in my file, and it works all the time.